# Angular 5 - how to wait for return value from asynchronous method

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

My `ngOnInit` method of my root `AppComponent` is doing some authentication as follows:

```
  token: SessionToken;
  authenticated: boolean;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.authenticate().subscribe(token => {
      if (token != null) {
        // authenticated
        this.token = token;
        this.authenticated = true;
      } else {
        // not authenticated
        this.authenticated = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is my `authenticate` method in `authService`:

```
// Authenticate user. Returns non-null token if authenticated, null token otherwise. 

  token: MyCustomToken;

  authenticate(): Observable<MyCustomToken> {
    return this.http.get<SessionToken>(this.url)
      .pipe(
        tap(token => this.token = token),
        catchError(this.handleError<SessionToken>('authenticate'))
      );
  }
```

Then in that same service, I also have another method that checks whether the user is authenticated, by checking whether the token that was returned from the `authenticate` call was null or not:

```
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    if (this.token != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Finally, in my `canActivate` method of my authentication guard, I want to call that `isAuthenticated` method to check whether the user is authenticated before displaying the page:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>|boolean {
        console.log("in canActivate() of authentication guard."); 

        let val = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
        console.log(`Is authenticated? ${val}`); // printing false, even though the server returned a non-null token when I called authenticate in AppComponent
        return val;
}
```

The problem is, `this.authService.isAuthenticated()` in the `canActivate` method is returning false, even though the server returned a non-null token when I called authenticate in AppComponent.

What seems to be happening is `canActivate` is being called *before* the token is returned from the server in the call to `authenticate` in `AppComponent`, because `authenticate` is an *asynchronous* call.

So is there a way I can wait for the asynchronous call to complete or some other workaround?

Comment: so why don't you use chaining in your app using .then() etc? I am trying to understand is there a reason you can't do it via that approach?

Comment: also it would be helpful to describe what is the high level problem you where trying to solve with this. As your current solution might not be optimal. Seems like what you have is pretty "classic" case of a startup cycle for an app. If I am wrong and there is something unique about it - share?:)

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I never knew about that. How do I do it?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Yes, I just need to authenticate the user before the app starts.

Comment: feel free to ask more questions cause I know its not easy to write this part of the app (cause of async). And I would suggest you expand your answer with your actual full code once you tried. Then we can help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **"pseudo" code** that should help guide you in how to write some of the startup cycle methods which involve a lot of async. This one typically lives in app.component.ts.

This below also assumes your app has some form of local persistence (library such as localForage etc that abstracts and makes it easy to access indexeddb or websql persistence on the client).

Local persistence is important to help store user contextual data (like whether intro was shown etc) which is used to define startup cycle:

```
  initApp() {
    // this below collects all locally persistent data about user:
    this.getAppContext().then(()=>{
      // here some additional activities depending on your app:
      this.statusBar.hide();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      // then we proceed with startup cycle:
      this.startUpCycle();
    })
  }

  // gather application context: userData, appIsOnline, JWT token, appIsCordova etc
  async getAppContext() {
    // foundation here is a global service that is available across the app:
    const promise = await this.foundation.storage.get("___userData")
    if (promise) {
      this.foundation.userData = promise;
      this.foundation.userID = promise.user._id;
      this.foundation.introShown - promise.introShown;
      this.foundation.appHasUserData = true;
    } else {
      this.foundation.appHasUserData = false;
    }
  };

  startUpCycle() {
  // if no data stored locally - we direct user to signup / intro page:
  if (!this.foundation.appHasUserData) {
      set signup page as the root page
      END
      // if data was persisted before:
  } else {
      (initalize local storage with user data).then(() => {
        (load additional user data like documents etc).then(() => {
          (check JWT as part of this.foundation.userData).subscribe(() => {
            do stuff
          set root page as the main page
            initialise FCM / notifications
            sync to remote database
          }, (err) => {
            set root page to login page
          })
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Also ideally I would recommend to draft the diagram that has the logic of what and in which order should happen in your app before you write the code. Example (its Ionic/Angular app that can be offline and on cordova/native as well);

[image]